# How to debug Android Native crash log (perhaps multiple webview issue)?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, java-native-interface

I got a crash that I couldn't find linked directly to my code, then I found that it is a native crash. The backtrace is like this

```
Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(259)] Please include Java exception stack in crash report
    '
        r0 00000000  r1 00003c12  r2 00000006  r3 00000008
        r4 7cb80978  r5 00000006  r6 7cb80920  r7 0000010c
        r8 7cb7ffad  r9 7cb7ffac  sl 7cb80408  fp 7cb80404
        ip 0000000b  sp 7cb7ff38  lr b3eab4b7  pc b3eadd20  cpsr 600f0010

A/DEBUG: backtrace:
        #00 pc 0004ad20  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
        #01 pc 000484b3  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+34)
        #02 pc 0001dd89  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
        #03 pc 00019511  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+34)
        #04 pc 00017150  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
        #05 pc 0079a29b  /data/app/com.android.chrome-1/base.apk (offset 0xfa5000)
```

I'm wondering how can I utilize this to help me locate my problem. I know this is too broad, difficult to locate the problem in my code. So I'm wondering if anyone can give any instruction or direction to utilize this log? To give more information, I have multiple webviews when it crashes, is it possible of memory fragmentation error? If so, what should I do? Recreate webview?
Seems there are something before this

```
System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 25 col 46 failed
        at net.sqlcipher.CursorWindow.getLong_native(Native Method)
05-29 15:38:24.016 22757-23608/com.boxer.email W/System.err:     at net.sqlcipher.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:450)
        at net.sqlcipher.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:110)
        at net.sqlcipher.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:201)
        at net.sqlcipher.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:230)
05-29 15:38:24.017 22757-23608/com.boxer.email W/System.err:     at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:202)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:202)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:202)
        at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:202)
```

Comment: `com.android.chrome` suggests the problem is coming from a WebView.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani looks so, do you have any suggestion, how to I debug to locate the problem the next step? Again, I know this is a very broad question, please give anything you can come up with.

Comment: The message suggests that your logcat might contain a Java exception stack reported, too.

Comment: @AlexCohn I did find socket timeout exception, but don't think it will cause the crash here.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani I searched again. The scenario is that, I have multiple webviews inside one view. Because I have to use multiple webviews to improve UI|UX instead of just using one. Do you think this is because of memory fragmentation error?

Comment: @AlexCohn I have a couple webviews to display in this situation, perhaps that's the reason?

Comment: @litaoshen WebViews can cause crashes in different ways (out of memory for example). The data you provided is not sufficient to get to the root cause of this issue. If I were you, I'd start by trying to take away components until I find the one that causes the problem and only then try to debug it and see what can be done to resolve the crash. You can probably add some more logs to find out what is the last operation that happened before the crash.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani thanks, will try it out.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani After trying a few times, I got some more info. So in the beginning it some how got something like `Index 24 of size 24`, then after forcing some checks it gave me error which I added in the updates. But I don't think it is a db issue since I actually could use another set of code to access DB and seems fine.

Answer (score 4):

try to destroy webview in `onDestroy()`  method because WebView Client or Chromium client is loading data even after your activity or fragment destroyed.

try this :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (myWbView != null)
        myWbView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**OR**

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    webView=null; // remove webView, prevent chromium to crash
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have file with symbols consider using ndk-stack 
Sample usage:
adb logcat | ~/Library/Android/android-ndk-r17/ndk-stack -sym /armeabi-v7a/

this would show functions where crash is.

Official link:https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack